# search and sorting in c program?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, search, bubble-sort

I am writing a program which receives some numbers from the client and then sort them with Bubble sorting function and the other function which receive one number from client and then search it between the other number with binary search function .Please inform me what the problem of this program is?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bobsort (int);
int searchi (int);

void main ()
{

    int num, i;
    printf ("Enter Count Number \n");
    scanf ("%d", &num);
    int array[num];
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        printf ("Enter Number %d \n", i);
        scanf ("%d", &array[i - 1]);
    }

    bobsort (num);
    searchi (num);

    getch ();

//return 0;
}

//**** function bobsort
void bobsort (int n)
{
    int c, d, swap;
    for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
            if (array[d] > array[d + 1]) {      /* For decreasing order use < */
                swap = array[d];
                array[d] = array[d + 1];
                array[d + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    printf ("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        printf ("%d\n", array[c]);

    // return 0;
}

//**** function search
int searchi ()
{
    int c, first, last, middle, n, search;

    printf ("Enter value to find\n");
    scanf ("%d", &search);

    first = 0;
    last = n - 1;
    middle = (first + last) / 2;

    while (first <= last) {
        if (array[middle] < search)
            first = middle + 1;
        else if (array[middle] == search) {
            printf ("%d found at location %d.\n", search, middle + 1);
            break;
        } else
            last = middle - 1;

        middle = (first + last) / 2;
    }
    if (first > last)
        printf ("Not found! %d is not present in the list.\n", search);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). In particular, you need to describe your problem in more detail. For example, sample input, expected output and actual output. It is also good form to describe how you have attempted to debug this yourself and what data you collected from your debugging. Finally, ask a specific question rather than just a broad "it doesn't work, what's the problem?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several compilation errors, below I rewrote your code with comments so that it can compile. The actual functions seem to work just fine

The most important change was passing `array` to both functions. It is passed as `int*` so that the functions can modify `array` in the context of `main`

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Neither one of these need to return a value, both are now void
// Both need to have array passed, added int*
void bobsort(int, int*);
void searchi(int, int*);

int main() {
    int num, i;

    printf("Enter Count Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int array[num];
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        printf("Enter Number %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i-1]);
    }

    // Pass array to both functions
    bobsort(num, array);
    searchi(num, array);

    // Don't know what this was supposed to be, commented out
    //getch();

    return 0;
}

// Receives array from main
void bobsort(int num, int* array) {
    int c, d, swap;
    for (c = 0; c < num-1; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < num-c-1; d++) {
            if (array[d] > array[d+1]) {
                swap = array[d];
                array[d] = array[d+1];
                array[d+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");
    for (c = 0 ; c < num; c++)
        printf("%d\n", array[c]);
}

// Receives array from main
void searchi(int num, int* array) {
    int c, first, last, middle, search;

    printf("Enter value to find\n");
    scanf("%d", &search);

    first = 0;
    last = num-1;
    middle = (first+last)/2;

    while (first <= last) {
        if (array[middle] < search)
            first = middle+1;
        else if (array[middle] == search) {
            printf("%d found at location %d\n", search, middle+1);
            break;
        }
        else
            last = middle-1;

        middle = (first+last)/2;
    }
    if (first > last)
        printf("Not found! %d is not present in the list\n", search);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your bubble sort function.  You need to replace the outer for loop with a while loop and when you do the swap, you need to set a flag to indicate that the swap happened.  Also, your code defines array inside of the main function and not as a global variable, so you will need to pass a pointer to your array as well because array is outside the scope in which bobsort is in (in other words, bobsort can't see array). Corrected code below:

```
//*********************************function bobsort
void bobsort(int n, int *array)
{
 int   d, swap, flag;  

  flag = 1;
  while (flag != 0)
  {
    flag = 0;
    for (d = 0; d < n - 1; d++)
    {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
      {
        swap       = array[d];
        array[d]   = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = swap;
        flag = 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

In your main function, change the call to this:

```
bobsort(num, &array[0]);
```

That way, the sorting function can access the array and know what size it is.  Doing it this way, you exit the sort routine when there are no more swaps and the list is sorted.  As a side note, as far as sorting algorithms go, Bubble sort is very slow and inefficient.  A comb sort is a better routine and is slightly more complicated.  A pseudo code example of a comb sort routine is shown below ([from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort)):

```
function combsort(array input)
    gap := input.size //initialize gap size
    shrink := 1.3 //set the gap shrink factor

    loop until gap = 1 and swapped = false
        //update the gap value for a next comb. Below is an example
        gap := int(gap / shrink)
        if gap < 1
          //minimum gap is 1
          gap := 1
        end if

        i := 0
        swapped := false //see bubblesort for an explanation

        //a single "comb" over the input list
        loop until i + gap > input.size //see shellsort for similar idea
            if input[i] > input[i+gap]
                swap(input[i], input[i+gap])
                swapped := true // Flag a swap has occurred, so the
                                // list is not guaranteed sorted
            end if
            i := i + 1
        end loop

    end loop
end function
```

I have personally used this routine for sorting and it works quite well.  As for your binary search function, I don't see anything obviously wrong with it.

EDIT:  I just saw that your search function is also missing the array in the parameter list.  Add it just like I did with the bubble sort function and call it the same way using the & operator.  You are also using n uninitialized.  You need to pass the size of the array to the search function as well.  I rewrote the function as shown below:

```
//**** function search
int searchi (int n, int *array)
{
    int c, first, last, middle, search;

    printf ("Enter value to find\n");
    scanf ("%d", &search);

    first = 0;
    last = n - 1;
    middle = (first + last) / 2;

    while (first <= last) {
        if (array[middle] < search)
            first = middle + 1;
        else if (array[middle] == search) {
            printf ("%d found at location %d.\n", search, middle + 1);
            break;
        } else
            last = middle - 1;

        middle = (first + last) / 2;
    }
    if (first > last)
        printf ("Not found! %d is not present in the list.\n", search);

    return 0;
}
```

Then you call with the following code:

```
searchi(num, &array[0]);
```

That should make it work correctly.  As a side note, when you get compiler errors, pay attention to what it is telling you and try to correct them.  I don't know what compiler that you are using, but clang is better at pointing out errors and explaining what the problem is than gcc.  One time using gcc, I had some weird error that it wasn't really specific about.  After 3 hours, I found that the problem was a conflict with a definition in some obscure, far flung header file that was buried in the system that was being included from 5 levels down.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to take a while. Let's start with the basics, first `main` is an of type `int` (regardless of what some compilers let you get away with) and it returns an integer value `0` or greater (no negative values returned to the shell):

```
int main (void)
 ...
return 0;
```

Next, always initialize your variables. Attempting to read from an uninitialized value is **undefined behavior** (bad). When looping over array elements, the loop starts at '0' (not '1' with adjusted elements):

```
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf (" enter array[%d] ", i);
        scanf ("%d", &array[i]);
    }
```

What were you thinking with your function definitions and declarations? You can't define a function prototype as:

```
int searchi (int);
```

and then declare your function as:

```
void searchi ();
```

That is absolute basic (`apples != apples`) housekeeping. How are you ever going to access the array elements and know how many there are unless you **pass the array** and the **number of elements** as arguments to your functions. i.e.:

```
void bobsort (int *array, int n)
void searchi (int *array, int n)
```

You have to put effort into your code and fix the simple things if you ever hope to have anything else work.

Next, your `bobsort` code was indexed incorrectly, you must use:

```
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < n - 1; d++) {
            /* For decreasing order use < */
            if (array[d] > array[d + 1]) {
                swap = array[d + 1];
                array[d + 1] = array[d];
                array[d] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't recall what I did to `searchi`, it was fairly close except for the declaration. Fixing all the issues above results in something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bobsort (int*, int);
void searchi (int*, int);

int main (void)
{
    int num = 0, i = 0;
    int array[num];

    printf ("\n no. of array elements: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf (" enter array[%d] ", i);
        scanf ("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    bobsort (array, num);
    searchi (array, num);
    // getch ();

    return 0;
}

/* function bobsort */
void bobsort (int *array, int n)
{
    int c, d, swap;
    c = d = swap = 0;

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < n - 1; d++) {
            /* For decreasing order use < */
            if (array[d] > array[d + 1]) {
                swap = array[d + 1];
                array[d + 1] = array[d];
                array[d] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    printf ("\nSorted list in ascending order:\n\n");

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        printf ("%d\n", array[c]);
}

/* function search */
void searchi (int *array, int n)
{
    int first, last, middle, search;
    first = last = middle = search = 0;

    printf (" enter value to find: ");
    scanf ("%d", &search);

    first = 0;
    last = n - 1;
    middle = (first + last) / 2;

    while (first <= last) {
        if (array[middle] < search)
            first = middle + 1;
        else if (array[middle] == search) {
            printf ("%d found at location %d.\n", search, middle + 1);
            break;
        } else
            last = middle - 1;

        middle = (first + last) / 2;
    }
    if (first > last)
        printf ("Not found! %d is not present in the list.\n", search);
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_bsort_srch

 no. of array elements: 5
 enter array[0] 9
 enter array[1] 3
 enter array[2] 5
 enter array[3] 8
 enter array[4] 4

Sorted list in ascending order:

3
4
5
8
9
 enter value to find: 8
8 found at location 4.
```

All of these issues should have been painfully obvious to you if you were compiling with **warnings** enabled and then reading what the compiler was telling you. When ever you build anything, do enable the warnings, at minimum:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o progname progname.c
```

(just substitute your compiler exe name for `gcc`) If you are using some IDE, then every IDE provides a config to specify your compiler options, make sure you enable warnings. They are there to help you identify issues with your code that will lead to potentially unreliable operation. Unless you take the time to fix the warnings, you are running at your own risk.

Really, years of development has gone into the compiler to have it identify where problems exist and what the problems are. It even gives you the exact line number the error or warning was found on. You simply must take the time to read the output and fix the errors and warnings. If you are unsure what a warning or error means, just type it into a search engine (i.e. **"C copy/paste warning or error"**) You will get a wealth of information on what is wrong, what to look for, and how to go about fixing it. Good luck.